# To go to a distance which is far with the speed of linght in time smaller than the distance light can not go

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, faster-than-light, observers

My question is this say that we have a particle and this particle will go to a place that is 200 light years away and we want to go there in 10 light years. Is this possible?

Comment: No, you can't travel faster than light.

Comment: My friend has talked about that and said it is possible because there will be time delay.

Comment: Probably he didn't say delay but dilation. We see the time of the moving particle dilate, i.e. we see it's time pass much slower than ours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can because of length contraction. Imagine you are inside a rocket travelling at a speed $v$ and you want to get to some planet 200 light years away in ten years. The formula for length contraction is $$L=\frac{L_0}{\gamma_v}$$
with $L_0$ the length of an object at rest and $L$ the length of that object according to someone travelling at speed $v$. The denominator is called the *Lorentz factor* (very common in relativity). It gets bigger at higher speeds and is defined to be $$\gamma_v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

So if you put a stick between the earth and the planet is 200 lightyears away, it would be shorter for you than for someone on earth, which means you have to travel less distance. Using the formula for velocity you get
$$v=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}=\frac{200/\gamma_v \text{ ly}}{10 \text{ y}}$$
$$\frac{v}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}=20c$$ 
which you can solve to get $v=\frac{20}{\sqrt{401}}c\ $  or 99.88% the speed of light

Note that you get $c$ from dividing light years by years. As a recap you basically solved 'how fast do I need to go to shrink the distance enough to get there in time'.

Answer (score 1):

He must have been referring to the proper time of the particle. Something moving very fast with respect to you get Lorentz contracted by a factor $\gamma = 1/ \sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}$. When$v$ gets close to $c$, the velocity of light, this gets arbitrarily large, so that from the point of view of the particle the 200 light-years can appear arbitrarily short. From the point of view of an external observer it would take 200 years + a little bit.

If I remember correctly, the most energetic cosmic ray ever observed had a $\gamma$ such that the 100000 light-years diameter of the milky way would take it a few seconds to bridge in its own reference frame.